# Provision a VM as part of an Azure Devops build pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-virtual-machine

I have a build pipeline that is working pretty well currently in Azure DevOps. As part of the pipline/build process, I create an artifact, which is published and reachable. After that, I'd like to do the following:

- Create/Start Up a new VM (Windows)
- Grab the now published artifact, unzip it and run the executable within
- Run the integration tests
- Close the VM

I've looked around the Azure documentation but cannot find much that discusses this sort of solution. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing built-in (like a readymade task `create a vm`), so you can use any way to create a VM in Azure. Azure powershell, Azure Cli, ARM Templates, SDK calls. whatever works for you.

You would need to open ssh\winrm to talk to that vm to deploy stuff to it. thats about it. You can find lots of examples on how to create a VM online. VSTS got tasks for Azure Powershell\Cli\ARM Tempaltes so you dont need to handle auth.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a VM using ARM templates with the task 'Azure Resource Group Deployment'

With a separate task 'Powershell on target machine' you can run a powershell script on the target VM, if you put the downloading, unzipping and running of this exe in this script you should be able to perform the tasks you need.

You could also look into the 'invoke-azurermvmruncommand' powershell command, this allows you to run a powershell script in the vm. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/invoke-azurermvmruncommand?view=azurermps-6.11.0